# Representing certain linear maps on a direct sum decomposition of a free module of finite rank

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose that $R^n \cong M \oplus N$ where $R$ is a commutative ring and $M$ and $N$ are $R$-modules.

Consider a map of the form $f \oplus 0_N: M \oplus N \to M \oplus N$ where $f: M \to M$ is a linear map.

This can be represented by some $n\times n$ matrix over $R$, but do we know anything about how certain parts of this matrix look?

That is, is there some basis for $M\oplus N$ for which the matrix representing $f\oplus 0_N$ has some known form?

If we're in the category of vector spaces, then it is obvious, but in our case $M$ and $N$ may not be free.

I know this question is a bit vague, but any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: If $n$ is finite, you don't have to assume that $M$ is finitely generated, it follows from the hypotheses. Also, I don't see how anything changes if  $R$ is a field: there is a basis in which the matrix would be nice, but the matrix in the standard basis of $R^n$ would have no reason to be special

Comment: @Max A submodule of a finitely generated free module need not be finitely generated. If $R$ is a field, then the matrix will be a block diagonal matrix consisting of the matrix for $f$ and the matrix for $0_N$.

Comment: I know, but $R^n=M\oplus N$ implies that $M$ is a quotient of $R^n$. No, if $R$ is a field, there is a basis in which the matrix looks like that, but the matrix in the standard basis need not look anything like that

Comment: @Max You're right on both. I guess what I want to know is whether there is some basis for which $f \oplus 0_N$ has some nice form.

Comment: If $R$ is a PID or a local ring, then you have the same theorem as for fields (because for both of these, projective modules are free). I don't know about more general statements